# Whats the point of the human function in the Nicomachean Ethics?

Tags: ethics, aristotle

Is "the good" Aristotle mentions for a human just the same as saying the eudaimonia for a human (since that would seem to connect the two)? Otherwise, I do not see how he arrives at a conclusion which connects function and eudaimonia.

Further, how does (or does he?) Aristotle justify that doing the human function well actually gets you something like eudaimonia? For example, it seems plausible to me that someone could learn the virtues and exercise their rational soul accordingly and still lead a life that is worse off than if they hadn't, supposing they did not already want to lead that kind of life. **Does he think all humans want to lead a virtuous and rational life and people who think otherwise are delusional?**

So, I do not see how the human function argument gets people to eudaimonia. Can someone explain why he thinks doing the human function well gets you a happy/eudaimon life?